# Losing enum type information in for in loop

Tags: typescript, enums

In the below example, keys of `myColors` are of type `Color`. However I'm having trouble retaining that information when looping over the `myColor` object.

```
enum Color {
  Red = 'RED',
  Green = 'GREEN',
}

type MyColors = {
  [C in Color]?: string;
}

const myColors: MyColors = {
  [Color.Red]: '#8B0000',
}

for (const [name, hex] of Object.entries(myColors)) {
  // name is of type string here instead of Color
}
```

Using a regular `for in` loop, or `Object.keys(myColors)` also converts the enum key to a string.

Is there any way to retain the type of the keys when looping over an object's properties? If not, how can I assert that `name` in my loop is of type `Color`?

Comment: I've updated my answer. No need for a helper function anymore, if you're happy to add a declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript's definition for `Object.entries` is overloaded, but both overloads use string, explicitly, as the key type. From `lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns an array of key/values of the enumerable properties of an object
>  * @param o Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
>  */
> entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
>
> /**
>  * Returns an array of key/values of the enumerable properties of an object
>  * @param o Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
>  */
> entries(o: {}): [string, any][];
> ```

I'm sure there's a good reason for it. :-) But you can define your own `entries` that doesn't use `string`:

```
// Our `entries` function
function entries<T>(o: T): [keyof T, T[keyof T]][] {
    return Object.entries(o) as unknown as [keyof T, T[keyof T]][];
}
```

Then it works:

```
for (const [name, hex] of entries(myColors)) {
  // type of `name` is `Color` now
}
```

Taking it further, I've found that if I add the following declaration:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    /**
     * Returns an array of key/values of the enumerable properties of an object
     * @param o Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
     */
    entries<T>(o: T): [keyof T, T[keyof T]][];
}
```

With that, your original code works as you expected:

```
for (const [name, hex] of Object.entries(myColors)) {
  // type of `name` is `Color` now
}
```

(I double-checked this with the real compiler, not just the playground, by having `const n: Color = name;` in the loop body. TypeScript complains about it without the declaration, but with the declaration it's happy.)

**But**, some issues in the TypeScript issue list make me think that definition may cause trouble with other kinds of things you'd pass `Object.entries`, specifically [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26010) and [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208). So you might want to have the separate function (which will get JIT'd away, most likely) and use it where relevant.

Comment: You're a life saver, thanks! I wonder why this isn't in the official definition for `entries`...

Comment: @L.Berger - My pleasure, I learned at least two things. :-) Me too about the definition. It wouldn't surprise me if it uses a relatively-recent feature and the previous definition just hasn't been updated to use it.

Comment: @L.Berger - Searching around the TypeScript issues list, it looks like the above causes trouble in some other situations, so you might be best off sticking with your own `entries` utility function (don't worry, a decent JavaScript engine will JIT it away :-) ). Start [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26010) if you want to go on the journey, most of it seems to be summed up in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208).